# Char array is directly printing the contents of the array without requiring me to specify the index positions, it is great but how is this happening?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, char

Char array is directly printing the contents of the array without requiring me to specify the index positions, it is great, but how is this happening? Can someone please explain me what's happening behind the scenes?

Here is what I mean exactly:

```
int mane[]={2,5,6,7};

char jane[]={'s','w','a','p'};
```

If we print the mane array directly it shows some gibberish value, but if we print the array jane[] it perfectly prints the array values without using the index positions of the array, how?

I'm expecting an explanation of what is happening with the char array and the integer array.

Comment: What code do you use to print each of the arrays?

Comment: FYI, please define arrays as `int[] mane` and `char[] jane`. The syntax you use is supported, but generally not the recommended syntax. In any case, you're probably using `System.out.println`, and a `PrintStream` has a [specific overload for `char[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[])), and not for `int[]`, which will use the `println(Object)` version, which means it uses the default `toString`, because arrays do not have a custom `toString` method.

Comment: BTW: The output is not "gibberish", it is the class name (`[I` for `int[]`) followed by `@` followed by the hexadecimal value of the 32-bit identity hashcode of the array (e.g. `5b37e0d2`)

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm expecting an explanation of what is happening with the char array and the integer array."*

The *println* method is *[over-loaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*.

This means that the *int* *array* is using a different method than the *char* *array*.

For an *Object*, the *int* *array*, the *[String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object))* method is called.

- *[PrintStream (Java SE 20 & JDK 20) – println(Object x)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object))*
- *[GitHub – OpenJDK – java/io/PrintStream#println(Object)](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#L1186)*

  - *[GitHub – OpenJDK – java/lang/String#valueOf(Object)](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L4481)*

And, for the *char* *array*, a *[Writer#write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html#write(char%5B%5D))* method is used, to print the values.

- *[PrintStream (Java SE 20 & JDK 20) – println(char[] x)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char%5B%5D))*
- *[GitHub – OpenJDK – java/io/PrintStream – println(char[])](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#L1148)*

  - *[GitHub – OpenJDK – java/io/PrintStream – implWriteln(char[])](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#L775)*

    - *[GitHub – OpenJDK – java/io/Writer#write(char[])](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/Writer.java#L241)*

To print the *int* *array*, use the *[Arrays#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))* method.

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mane));
```

Output

```
[2, 5, 6, 7]
```

Alternately, use an *[Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html)* *array*, and the *[List#of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...))* method.

```java
Integer mane[]={2,5,6,7};
System.out.println(List.of(mane));
```